# In Munchkin, do you level up after breaking down a door, if you don't kill a monster?

Tags: munchkin

Take the following sequence of events:

1. I break down a door and pickup a door card which is not a monster.
2. I loot the room and pick up a card and put it in my pack.
3. No other players take any action.
4. I end my turn.

Should I level up in this case?

EDIT: For anyone else asking this question, it was based on a mis-reading of the rules. You do NOT represent leveling up by moving to the next room. You are meant to use tokens or a counter to track your level. Don't be thrown off by the fact that there are 10 rooms and you need to get to level 10 to win.

EDIT2: OK, I'm more confused about this. It seems there are different versions, which don't even have the board with 10 rooms. In which case, I guess the rooms on the board DO represent levels, but is meant to be used like a level counter, not a representation of players physically entering rooms. I guess if it was a later edition, it would make sense that it might not entirely mesh with the rules as originally written.

Comment: How is this question unfocused?

Comment: A basic principle of games in general is that you generally can't do something unless there's something that says you can. Just because the rules don't say you can't level up, that doesn't mean you can.

Comment: While I understand people downvoting this question, I don't understand the VTC, and, like John, I understand even less the reason given. It really seems like someone just came across this and said "This is a stupid question" and then randomly picked a reason to VTC.

Comment: @Acccumulation well it implies in two ways that I enter the room (break down door, loot it), and the rooms _are_ the levels, hence my confusion

Comment: @JordanMorris where did you get that the rooms are the levels? that is absolutely not the case, levels are an abstract measure of your characters power and not your advancement through the dungeon.

Comment: @n0m4d3 to represent that your character has gone up a level, you literally move them to the next room

Comment: @jordanmorris that is very different from the rules i know where you use Tokens to represent your level https://munchkin.game/site-munchkin/assets/files/1138/munchkin_rules-1.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwj5u6GC1PWAAxUqbPEDHTgECSAQFnoECA0QAQ&usg=AOvVaw02BH6Okt3VKjWewLLYg0vZ

Comment: @n0m4d3 thanks, looks like I completely missed the part about level tokens/counters. Given that there are 10 rooms, and you move forward to fight, and level when you win a fight, that totally threw me off! No wonder people think I'm crazy with this question 

Comment: "there are 10 rooms" Are you refering to the board that tracks levels? Because I'm pretty sure that's a Deluxe Edition thing. Or, at the very least, something that's _not_ in every edition of the game. I mean, I get that it'd be hard for you to know this, if you've only seen editions that do have it.

Answer (score 7):

A few choise quotes from the [rules](https://munchkin.game/site-munchkin/assets/files/1138/munchkin_rules-1.pdf).

First, on the subject of Levels, we have **Character Stats**:

> **Level:** This is a measure of how generally buff and studly you are. When
> the rules or cards refer to your Level, capitalized, they mean this number.
> You gain a level when you kill a monster, or when a card says that you do.
> You can also sell Items to buy levels (see **Items**).

I'm going to ignore the buing of levels and "when a card says that you do" parts here, because they don't seem to be in constest. Here's what the rules say about how to gain Levels by *killing monsters.*

On **Rewards**:

> When you kill a monster, you get one level per monster, unless the
> monster card says something else, [...]

On **Conflicts Between Cards and Rules**

> You go up a level after combat only if you *kill* a monster.

On **Asking for Help**

> You level up for each slain monster. Your helper does not go up
> any levels . . . unless the helper is an Elf, in which case they gain one level for each monster slain.

I'd say the rules are pretty clear on this one; going up a level has less to do with kicking down the door, and more to do with *killing a monster* (either by finding one when you kick down the door, or by "finding one" when you *Look for Trouble*. Also note that you can *either* Look For Trouble *or* Loot The Room
I guess your character is too busy searching every nook and cranny of the room for even the tinyest bit of treasure to do anything else untill your next turn.

Comment: > "When you kill a monster, you get one level per monster". 
This does not say there is no other way to level up.

> "You go up a level after combat only if you *kill* a monster". 
Again, this does not say after combat is the only time you can level up. The emphasis on "kill" suggests the point of this instruction is merely that surviving combat isn't enough to level.

Comment: In fact, killing monsters isn't the only way to level up, because you can, for example, buy levels, so I don't think it's fair to say the instructions are unambiguous on the point of my question. 

> "too busy searching every nook and cranny of the room". 
Without entering said room?

Comment: @JordanMorris Generally, you can't expect the rules to exclude every situation where X doesn't happen. The rules give exactly three ways to gain levels; killing a monster, selling items, and when a card tells you to. They even clarify that you don't gain levels when helping or running away.

Comment: I believe you are mistaken as to what Levels represent. They don't represent your advancement through the dungeon/building, but your character's experience and skills.

Comment: > "you can't expect the rules to exclude every situation where X doesn't happen", except they do this a lot, as you've pointed out, and given the analogies used for levels being rooms, and the actions implying entering these rooms in at least two ways, I doubt I'm the only person who has wondered this question

Comment: I didn't include the other ways to level up, because I didn't want to complicate the answer, but rather focus on the clearing of the room. Also, you seem to have fallen to the classic trap of the game-designers-lacking-a-thesaurus (though with Munchkin, this may actually be intentional joke) https://www.giantitp.com/comics/oots0012.html